# Conditional Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: conditional-probability, monte-carlo

Suppose random variables $Z_i$ ~ $p(z)$ and $X_i$ ~ $p(x|z)$. $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ converges to $ E(X)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I think it converges, but can’t come up with the proof.

Comment: What do you get for the expected value of $X_1$?

Comment: Z_i is sampled out of p(z) and X_ij out of p(x|z_i). Thus, 1(NM) * Σ_i Σ_j X_ij converges. I find this fact, but this is the answer of the original question?

Answer (score 2):

If you generate $Z$ from $p_Z(z)$, then $X$ from $p(x\, \vert Z=z)$ you're simply generating $(X, Z)$ samples from $p_{XZ}(x, z)$ since $p_{XZ}(x, z) = p(x\, \vert Z=z) p_Z(z)$. So the expected value of each $X_i$ is $\text{E}X$. Take the sample average of $n$ of them and the answer stays the same.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good luck with your studies!